# Expected 'Value' on type 'Resource' to be an instance member

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2017

Since update from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017, I keep getting error for my binding code:

[image: Expected 'value' on type 'Resource' to be an instance member]

The program works just fine despite this error. When I rebuild the solution this information is gone until I change the xaml file. Resharper has to 2 solutions for this:

```
Binding Path=(resources:CaptionResources.WarehouseManagement), Source={StaticResource CaptionResources}
```

and

```
<controls:LabeledControl.Caption>
      <Binding Path="WarehouseManagement" Source="{StaticResource CaptionResources}" />
</controls:LabeledControl.Caption>
```

Is it any Visual Studio 2017 setting, that I miss?

Comment: No, most likely VS 2017 is just more strict in this regard than VS 2015 or before.

Comment: If it's building and running fine then I wouldn't call it an error per say, more of an FYI.  You mentioned ReSharper, it's possible that ReSharper is just highlighting this to you as possible code smell/improvement which in the grand scheme of things can be ignored.

Comment: I have switched off Resharper and the FYI remains. So this is clearly VS communication.

Answer (score 4):

Probably your WarehouseManagement property is static, so the message: "expected to be an instance member".
In this case you have to specify the full path like:

```
Caption={Binding Path=(namespace:className.WarehouseManagement)}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error Nested Types Not Supported

Comment: @dvdhns Are you using nested namespaces like 'namespace MyNamespace.NestedNamespace'?
In that case you have to reference the nested namespace like this ' xmlns:nested="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.NestedNamespace" ' and then ' "{Binding Path=(nested:MyClass.MyLabel)}" '